# ¿cómo hacer un programa que me imprima el resultado de la formula cuadrática en R?

Tags: r

este es mi código, pero no entiendo que tiene de malo D:, las variables de a,b y c las tiene que poner el usuario y me dice que las respuestas deberían ser -1 y 0 con los ejemplos 1,1,0 y a mi me da -0.25 y -0.75

```
message("Entradas:")
a=scan(nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)
b=scan(nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)
c=scan(nlines=1, quiet=TRUE)

message("Salidas:")
x=(-b+((b^2-4*a*c)^1/2))/2*a
x1=(-b-((b^2-4*a*c)^1/2))/2*a
print(x)
print(x1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Bienvenido Mayra Camacho a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Si ejecutas el código tal y como lo tienes, el programa no te devuelve los resultados que comentas, ya que hay un error al declarar a,b,c como elementos de tipo scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los resultados que esperas, basta con poner entre paréntesis el `1/2` y declarar los objetos `a,b,c` solamente con los valores deseados, sin crearlos como un objeto tipo `scan`. El código quedaría así:

```
message("Entradas:")
a=1
b=1
c=0

message("Salidas:")
x= (-b+((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/2*a
x1=(-b-((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/2*a
print(x)
print(x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad falta también un paréntesis en 2*a. Si (x + 1)*(x - (1/2) = 0 es la ecuación 2x^2 + x -1 = 0

```
a = 2
b = 1
c = -1

> message("Salidas:")
Salidas:
> x= (-b+((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/2*a
> x1=(-b-((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/2*a
> print(x)
[1] 2
> print(x1)
[1] -4

# PERO DEBE SER 0.5 y -1
> message("Salidas:")
Salidas:
> x= (-b+((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/(2*a)
> x1=(-b-((b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2)))/(2*a)
> print(x)
[1] 0.5
> print(x1)
[1] -1
```

puedes también usar la función `polyroot(z)`